# Trying to access the data from a document with an odd number of segments firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

The way I have my file directory set up is that I have a collection called users which contains a document called userUID2, this document (uerUID2) has both data and two sub collections. I would like to return all of the data in images, but when I try to set it up in code, it gives me the error - "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/userUID2/images has 3."
`

```
async function ListImageData()
{
  const docRef = doc(db, "users/", "userUID2/", 'images/');

  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}
```

`

I really cant think of a way to get passed this, and I sure what I am doing wrong has a very simple fix, but for some reason, I can't find it.

Also- if I try to change the docref to 'collection(.., .., ...) It throws a different error - "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Xc', but it was: a custom ta object"
I just thought that would be potentially helpful.

I am also curious about why firebase wont allow you to have three directories in the getDoc function.
[image: Image of My firestore]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution really far under another post -

```
    async function ListImageData()
{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userUID2", "images"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
}
```

Just had to use a foreach along with a query snapshot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).